# Google Maps API: Extremely high count of Distance Matrix Requests

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using Google Map API on my site for about a year. I use 3 Distance Matrix requests and 1 Direction API request on each map. There is only 1 map per page.

The requests/sec for the map is about 0.02. So the Distance Matrix requests are about 0.06 and the Direction API requests are about 0.02 accordingly.  But for certain hours of the day, while the map requests remain at 0.02 requests/sec, the Distance Matrix requests and the Direction API request jump to extremely high level. For example, the Distance Matrix requests can be as high as 4-5 requests/sec (or 15,000 per hour!). These huge requests start 3-5 AM and end 5-8 PM central time. The page containing the map has a page view count of about 200/hour only.

This started to happen since March. Since March I have been charged by Google $1,900 for these requests. The billing support at Google said this is a technical issue. I have searched everywhere and still not sure where to get technical support from Google.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Standard plan users are not entitled to technical support. Only Premium plan customers can get a technical support from Google.

Do you use a restricted API key? The first step might be adding an IP address restriction (web services) or HTTP referrer restriction (Maps JavaScript API) to your API key to be sure that it is used only by your application.

If you believe that API key is compromised just replace it with another one and add restrictions to new key. Once deleted the old key you will see if some part of your application is broken or not.

#### Update

Google introduced Google Maps Platform that replaces Google Maps Premium and Standard plans. In Google Maps platform you can file support case with Google Maps support team from your cloud project.

Comment: Thanks. I did add  HTTP referrer restrictions to my key. I also created new keys and the app using the new key has the same problem.

Comment: Do you use server side or client side Distance Matrix and Directions services? Do you respect usage limits established for services? In case of client side, you have a per session limit that doesn't allow too many requests from one session. Do you have a retry logic that may lead to this spike of failed requests? Have you tried [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#exponential-backoff)?

Comment: Hi, have you found what was causing the issue ?